# How to find inadvertent object pointer comparisons?

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm, compiler-warnings

Quick question - Is there a good way to find uses of `==` with objects instead of `isEqual:`?

Full story:

I had a bunch of code kind of like this:

```
typedef long DataKey;

DataKey x;
DataKey y;

if (x == y) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I now have a need to replace using a `long` for my `DataKey` with an object. After creating the class and doing a bunch of global search and replace, my code now is kind of like this:

```
@interface DataKey : NSObject

DataKey *x;
DataKey *y;

if (x == y) { // uh-oh - this is now bad
    // do stuff
}
```

Is there a warning I can enable in the compiler that warns about using the scalar operators in pointers? I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 with the LLVM 4.1 compiler. I haven't been able to find one.

Any other suggestions to help fix all of this code? This is not a trivial code base. There are hundreds of source files to deal with. This is a major refactoring effort.

Edit:

It would be great if there was a warning much like when you use assignment in an `if` condition instead of comparison. You can get a warning for this and use parenthesis to stop the warning.

Update:

Based on a suggestion in the comments, I added the `-Weverything` compiler option to a test project. This did not produce any desired result when comparing two object pointers with `==`.

Perhaps a combination of C++, overloading the `operator==` method, and getting some compiler warning/error when trying to use that operator can be achieved. I may post another question focused on this option.

Comment: Good question. How about [checking if it is a valid pointer](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html) and then adding a custom compiler warning as `#warning some text`. Not sure that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ACB I'm not sure how the information from that link can be applied here. I'm looking for (ideally) a compile time check. That link is for a runtime check.

Comment: It would be a reasonable compiler option to have, but I've never seen such, and I can't offhand think of any macro trick or whatever to force errors.

Comment: (Though I wonder if you could temporarily replace the class with a C++ class that would overload `==` in a way that would error out during compile.  But not sure you can even overload `==` in C++.)

Comment: @HotLicks Using a C++ was the first thing I tried actually for this very reason (operator== overload). But I couldn't create or call such a C++ class from Objective-C code, only Objectice-C++ (.mm) code. If there is a way - I'd be thrilled.

Comment: Well, you can temporarily change the attribute of your file to Ob_C++ through the file attributes window.  Depending on how you look at it, more complicated or less complicated than renaming the file outright.

Comment: Note that you don't need to run with the class, just compile and have it somehow force an error.

Comment: Why not try `-Weverything`? If the warnings generated include references to pointer comparisons then there must be a suitable flag. If they don't then there isn't.

Comment: @HotLicks That's the trick - how to make use of the operator== result in a compile error.

Comment: @Tommy Good idea. I just tried that in a simple test project - no warning received when I compared two objects using `==`. Bummer.

Comment: @rmaddy, You are correct. That is only for run time. I got what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no such warning, as comparing pointers for equality is pretty common and not all that commonly done in error. Your best bet will unfortunately be to go through any place DataKeys might be used this way and search for ==. Not very fun, I know.

Comment: Based on the number of newbie questions on SO where they attempt to compare two `NSString` objects using `==`, I'd have to disagree that using `==` by mistake isn't common. I bet it is as common as accidentally using assignment in a condition instead of comparison and there is compiler support for that issue.

Comment: @rmaddy: I suppose Chuck means that comparing pointers for equality is also very common; whereas assignment in a conditional statement is *usually* a mistake.

Comment: @mipadi And I'm saying that I disagree that comparing pointers for equality is common. At least in my own code it is very rare. I always add a comment to make it clear that I really do mean to compare using `==`. In fact, in almost 200k lines of code, I do it once. I have no doubt that others do it more often though.

Comment: @rmaddy: We're just explaining why there isn't a compiler option.

Comment: @rmaddy: Newbie questions where they compare NSStrings with == are just that: symptoms of inexperience. It is not actually a common error among C or Objective-C programmers, and it's easily spotted by a more experienced eye. Accidental assignment, on the other hand, is a common error even among experienced programmers because it's literally one character off from what you meant to do. I'm not saying I would object to this feature — I'm just explaining why a compiler writer wouldn't generally think to include it. (And comparing pointers is rather domain-dependent. Some do it a lot, some don't.)