# How can I force a compiler warning with operator==?

Tags: c++, objective-c, operator-overloading, compiler-warnings, objective-c++

This is a follow-on to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731097/how-to-find-inadvertent-object-pointer-comparisons).

I have a bunch of Objective-C code like this:

```
typedef long DataKey;

DataKey x;
DataKey y;

if (x == y) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I now have a need to change `DataKey` to be an object instead of `long`. If I create the class and do a bunch of global search and replace, my code now is kind of like this:

```
@interface DataKey : NSObject

DataKey *x;
DataKey *y;

if (x == y) { // uh-oh - this is now bad, I need isEqual: here
}
```

Since there is no compiler warning to detect using the `==` operator with two object pointers, I am looking for another solution.

One thought was to use a C++ class and overload the `==` operator in such a way that the compiler would complain.

I don't know C++ nearly as well as Objective-C. I've been able to write the C++ class and I now have code that actually results in the `operator==` method being called. Now I need help coming up with a way to tweak the code so I get a compiler warning.

Here's the C++ class:

```
class DataId {
public:
    DataId();

    bool operator==(const DataId &other);
};
```

Now I have some Objective-C++ code like this:

```
DataId x;
DataId y;

if (x == y) { // I need a compiler warning/error here
}
```

Is there a syntax trick I can come up to cause a compile error/warning on the `if` statement.

Comment: To all the people that voted to close this question - why? You all voted to close this AFTER it had already been answered. Obviously other people understood what I was asking. What was the point of your actions?

Comment: This drives me stark raving mad.  Programmers are supposed to be relatively smart people, and yet on SO, they frequently claim that *it's difficult to tell what is being asked here*.  They also seem not to understand the meaning of the `and` "operator" in English, as it pertains to *cannot be reasonably answered*.  Obviously, multiple people managed to do the impossible here, and answer your question.

Comment: This is a totally good question, and it shouldn't be closed. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just not defining an `operator==` at all? I don't think there's an implicit `operator==` for C++ classes. So your last snippet of code should throw a compiler error if you just leave off the definition of `operator==`.

Comment: OK, that was too easy. I missed this because initially when I tried I had declared `x` and `y` as `DataId *x`. I didn't remove the pointer until I attempted to implement the `operator==`. This turned out to be simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just making the `operator==` undefined and private should trigger an error. But if you want to compare 2 objects I dont see why you dont define the `operator==` as you need it.

```
bool operator==(const DataId &other){
    return IsEqual(other);//is this the function you want to compare with?
}
```

Comment: This is just an interim hack so I can find all uses of `==` in my code. Once I do that, I won't be using any C++ or Objective-C++ code at all.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You can use static_assert if you have access to C++11:</strike>

```
class DataId {
    // ...

    bool operator==(const DataId& other)
    {
        static_assert(false, "enter error message here.");
        return true;
    }
};
```

Just don't define operator == at all and the compiler will fail with an error at the point of use.

Comment: No you can't. That fails when the function is compiled, regardless of whether it's actually called anywhere.

Comment: I need a compile time solution but the compile issue should appear where I try to use the `==` operator, not in the `operator==` implementation.

Comment: That's correct. It's late. I'm going to bed :-p As others mentioned above, why not just not define operator == at all then?